# Dúvida sobre inserção de itens numa lista com índices dentro de colchetes em Python

Tags: python, lista, índices

É possível inserir itens numa lista através de métodos como por exemplo, `append()`, `extend()`, ou `insert()`. Mas também é possível inserir através de índices em colchetes, normalmente usados para substituir itens e não inseri-los.

Por exemplo: `lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, onde `lista[2:2] = "Q"` adiciona o caractere na posição 2 da lista. A lista ficaria assim: `[1, 2, 'Q', 3, 4]`.

Já se eu escrevesse `lista[2:3] = "Q"`, esse caractere substituiria o valor 3 fazendo com que a lista fique dessa forma: `[1, 2, 'Q', 4]`.

Então, a minha dúvida é: quando os índices são iguais, ocorre uma inserção e não uma substituição. É isso?

Quando eles são iguais, o Python interpreta como inserção? Há uma explicação mais técnica e detalhada para isso?

Comment: Neste caso o que está ocorrendo é que você está escrevendo por cima. De fato você está fazendo uma substituição.

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 6):

Antes de responder a sua pergunta é preciso conhecer dois conceitos simples. Subscrição e Fatiamento.

## Subscrição.

Essa sintaxe de usar um par de colchetes `[]` justaposto a um objeto chama-se [Subscrição](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) e serve para selecionar um item de uma sequência(string, tupla ou lista) ou de mapeamento (dicionário). Objetos definidos pelo usuário também suportam subscrição caso sejam definidos com um método [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). Possui a sintaxe:

```
objeto[ expressão ]
```

- Caso o `objeto` seja uma tipo de [`mapeamento`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=mapping%20types#mapping-types-dict)(dicionários) a `expressão` deve
  ser um objeto cujo valor é uma das chaves do mapeamento
  e a subscrição seleciona o valor no mapeamento que corresponde a essa
  chave.
- Quando o `objeto` for um tipo de [Sequencia](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=mapping%20types#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)(string, tupla ou lista) a `expressão` deverá ser um número inteiro ou uma [fatia](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings). Um inteiro para quando se quer selecionar um único objeto dentro da sequencia e uma fatia para quando se quer selecionar um intervalo de itens dentro da sequencia.

## Fatiamento.

O fatiamento é ato de selecionar um intervalo de itens em um objeto do tipo sequência. Sua sintaxe:

```
objeto[ limite_inferior : limite_superior  : passo ]
```

Onde:

- `limite_inferior` representa o índice do primeiro item a ser incluído na fatia. O valor na falta é 0.
- `limite_superior` representa o índice do primeiro item a **NÃO** ser incluído na fatia. O valor na falta é comprimento da lista.
- `passo` representa o incremento que será adicionado ao índice do item anterior na busca do próximo item. O valor na falta é 1.

Alguns exemplos simples:

```
>>> lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> lista[::2]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> lista[:3]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lista[3:]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

## Voltando a pergunta.

Quando se trata de sequência mutáveis, strings não se aplica pois é uma sequencia imutável, a subscrição por fatiamento além de selecionar items dentro de uma sequencia também pode ser usado para modificar seu conteúdo.

Sejam as operações:

- `s[i] = x` o item `i` de `s` é substituído por `x`.
- `s[i:j:k] = t` a fatia de `s` indo de `i` até `j` a cada `k` elementos, não incluindo `j`, é substituída pelo conteúdo do [iterável](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#iterable) `t`.
- `s[i:i] = t` insere os elementos do iterável `t` em `s` a partir do índice `i`.
- `del s[i:j:k]` remove de `s` a fatia indo de `i` até `j` a cada `k` elementos, não incluindo `j`.
- `s[i:j:k] = []` o mesmo que `del s[i:j:k]`.

Ciente disso na sua pergunta quando fez:

```
>>> lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> lista[2:2] = "Q"
>>> lista
[1, 2, 'Q', 3, 4]
```

Você não está simplesmente inserindo um caractere numa lista. Sim o resultado é uma string contendo um caractere inserido da lista mas a lógica que levou a esse resultado não é de uma simples inserção dum elemento na lista. Quando fez `lista[2:2] = "Q"` na verdade usou essa operação `s[i:i] = t` que insere os elementos do iterável `t` em `s` a partir do índice `i`, o que implica que não foi a string `"Q"` quem foi inserida dentro da lista mas os elementos do iterável `"Q"` foram inseridos na lista a partir do índice dois.
Caso a string as ser inserida seja maior que um caractere não será a string a ser inserida e sim os elementos que compõe o iterável. Exemplo:

```
>>> lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> lista[2:2] = "Qualidade"
>>> lista
[1, 2, 'Q', 'u', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'e', 3, 4]
```

No exemplo pode ser visto o string `"Qualidade"`, que é um iterável, tendo os seus elemento inseridos um a um na lista a partir de um índice. Caso a intenção inserir a string `"Qualidade" dentro da lista como um único elemento deve ser feita a inserção de um iterável populado com a string. Exemplo:

```
>>> lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> lista[2:2] = ["Qualidade"]
>>> lista
[1, 2, 'Qualidade', 3, 4]
```

E não é possível através dessa sintaxe inserir diretamente em uma sequencia um item que não seja iterável. Por exemplo:

```
>>> lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> lista[2:2] = 2.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only assign an iterable
```

Para inserir um item não iterável em uma sequencia ele precisa esta delimitado em um iterável. Exemplo:

```
>>> lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> lista[2:2] = [2.5]
>>> lista
[1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4]
```

E as mesmas considerações se aplicam ao seu exemplo `lista[2:3] = "Q"`. Veja:

```
>>> lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> lista[2:3] = "Qualidade"
>>> lista
[1, 2, 'Q', 'u', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'e', 4]
```

Apenas lembrando que `lista[2:3] = "Qualidade"`é a operação `s[i:j:k] = t` cujo a fatia de `s` indo de `i` até `j` a cada `k` elementos, *NÃO* incluindo `j`, é substituída pelo conteúdo do iterável `t`.

Para saber mais leia:

- [Operações comuns a sequencias.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=mapping%20types#common-sequence-operations)
- [Operação específicas a sequencias mutáveis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=mapping%20types#mutable-sequence-types)

Answer (score 0):

Como você mesmo disse, ao usar [2:2] o Python faz uma inserção na lista.
Já ao usar o [2:3], é executada uma substituição.

Experimente, por exemplo, fazer lista [:3] = "Q". Você irá verificar que tudo na
lista até índice 3 será substituído pelo "Q', ficando a lista = Q, 4.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]