# Regex - pegar apenas a primeira ocorrência de uma palavra em Python?

Tags: python, string, regex, pandas, dataframe

Em uma string, existem várias ocorrências de uma palavra, porém, quero pegar apenas a primeira ocorrência desta, como fazer?

Abaixo vem 'primeiro' duas vezes, porém, desejo somente o primeiro.

```
re.findall(r'primeiro',' o primeiro o segundo primeiro novamente')
```

Desde já grato.

Comment: Use `re.search()` ao invés do findall. Veja documentação [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Comment: Não faz muito sentido isso, pois se vc está buscando por "primeiro", o resultado será a própria palavra "primeiro". Faria sentido essa busca **se** a regex não fosse uma palavra fixa. O que exatamente você quer fazer?

Comment: A pergunta não faz sentido, caso queira obter o índice da primeira ocorrência de uma determinada palavra não precisa de regex, use o método [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find). Exemplo: `print(' o primeiro o segundo primeiro novamente'.find('primeiro'))`

Comment: obrigado @PauloMarques, o Ruan na reposta abaixo complementou bem essa questão.

Comment: @hkotsubo a palavra "primeiro" tem q vir na busca, porém na string tem ela duas vezes, mas desejo apenas a primeira ocorrência dela, o Ruan na reposta abaixo complementou bem essa questão grato.

Comment: @augusto-vasques, perdão meu desconhecimento no assunto e também em não conseguir esclarecer melhor a pergunta, o Ruan na reposta abaixo complementou bem essa questão, grato.

Comment: Mas se vc busca pela regex "primeiro", o retorno é a própria palavra "primeiro", então na prática bastaria saber se a palavra "primeiro" está na string:`if 'primeiro' in texto`, ou algo assim. Percebe que usar regex é meio inútil nesse caso? É como se eu quisesse buscar a letra "a" na palavra "banana", e quisesse como resultado a própria letra "a". Eu não preciso de regex pra buscar isso, eu só preciso saber se tem a letra "a" na palavra... As respostas abaixo são *overkill*, são um canhão pra matar mosca e é uma pena que nenhuma tenha sequer mencionado isso...

Comment: entendi @hkotsubo, mas em continuidade dessa pesquisa, a partir da primeira ocorrência, precisarei de outros detalhes como os 30 caracteres após somente a primeira ocorrência e depois dentro desse range selecionado identificar um padrão, não coloquei todos estes detalhes na pergunta inicial pois ficaria bem extenso.

Comment: Bom, vc viu o que eu comentei na sua outra pergunta? [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/498772/como-pegar-apenas-a-primeira-ocorr%c3%aancia-de-uma-palavra-com-regex-em-python#comment924589_498772). Talvez ajude...

Comment: sim, já estava usando algo parecido, grato.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Os métodos `re.findall` e `re.search` vão retornar as ocorrências em uma lista e um [Match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), respectivamente:

```
['primeiro', 'primeiro']
<re.Match object; span=(3, 11), match='primeiro'>
```

O Match object, resultado do método `re.search` tem um método `span()` que retorna uma tupla. **Seus itens indicam os índices do começo e final da "substring" desejada dentro da string inicial, respectivamente**. Você pode acessar os índices da string desejada como no exemplo:

```
string = ' o primeiro o segundo primeiro novamente'
resultado = re.search(r'primeiro', string)
comeco, fim = resultado.span() # (3, 11)
print(string[comeco:fim]) # primeiro
```

Se preferir, o método [`Match.group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) pode ser usado para retornar a primeira ocorrência completa do Match object:

```
resultado.group() # primeiro
```

Comment: muito interessante sua resposta. usarei aqui. agora tenho q pensar como posso fazer isso usando o texto contido em uma coluna de um dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Devido a falta clareza da pergunta, a mesma pode ser interpretada das seguintes formas:

- Como saber se uma palavra está presente num texto?
- Como obter índice da primeira ocorrência duma palavra num texto?
- Como obter a fatia dentro duma string onde se encontra a primeira ocorrência duma palavra num texto?

Independente de qual realmente seja a pergunta não se usa regex para nenhum dos três casos. Expressões regulares são um recurso de processamento caro e pesado e deve ser utilizado apenas para encontrar padrões de caracteres ou bytes nunca para encontrar uma palavra definida pois existem recursos menos custosos.

Não entenda mal, eu amo trabalhar com Regex mas apesar do nome simpático, as expressões regulares são um caso de gramática linear dentro da [Hierarquia Chomsky](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180927/137387) ou seja ao usar regex você está carregando um parser([autômato finito determinístico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260864/137387)) para dentro de seu programa o que significa que está abdicando de recursos de memória e tempo de processamento. Então use Regex sim, mas quando necessário por exemplo:

- encontrar palavras num texto que contenham grafia especial ou abjeta.
- encontrar palavras num texto que contenham determinados encontros vocálicos.
- sequencias alfanuméricas especiais.
- quebrar texto usando separadores variáveis.
- separar texto em símbolos léxicos.
- tudo que possa ser relacionado a busca e vasculha baseados em padrões de repetição de caracteres.

Feita a introdução vamos a(s) pergunta(s).

## Como saber se uma palavra está presente num texto?

Para saber se uma palavra está presente num texto utiliza o operador python [in](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations). Os operadores `in` e `not in` testam continência. `x in s` retorna `True` se `x` está contido em `s` e `False` caso contrário. `x not in s` retorna a negação de `x in s`.

```
s = ' o primeiro o segundo primeiro novamente'

print('primeiro' in s)                          #True
print('segundo' in s)                           #True
print('terceiro' in s)                          #False
```

## Como obter índice da primeira ocorrência duma palavra num texto?

Para obter índice da primeira ocorrência duma palavra num texto utilize o método builtin `str.find()`.

> [**`str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`**](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)
> Retorna o menor índice na string onde a substring `sub` é encontrado dentro da fatia `s[start:end]`. Argumentos opcionais como `start` e `end` são interpretados como na [notação de fatiamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/458546/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-itens-numa-lista-com-%C3%ADndices-dentro-de-colchetes-em-pyt/458596#). Retorna `-1` se `sub` não for localizado.

```
s = ' o primeiro o segundo primeiro novamente'

print(s.find('primeiro'))                       #3
print(s.find('segundo'))                        #14
print(s.find('terceiro'))                       #-1
```

## Como obter a fatia dentro duma string onde se encontra a primeira ocorrência duma palavra num texto?

Para obter fatia dentro duma string onde se encontra a primeira ocorrência duma palavra num texto basta somar índice da primeira ocorrência da palavra mais o seu comprimento obtido com a função builtin [len()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#len). *Lembrando que [nem sempre o comprimento de uma string é comprimento visual da mesma string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450163/137387)*

```
s = ' o primeiro o segundo primeiro novamente'

for p in ("primeiro", "segundo", "terceiro"):
  if p not in s:
    print(f"Palavra \"{p}\" não encontrada.")
  else:
    print((p, i:= s.find(p), len(p) + i))

#('primeiro', 3, 11)
#('segundo', 14, 21)
#Palavra "terceiro" não encontrada.
```