# Existe documentação no padrão ECMAScript que assegure que a um array ao ser passado como assessor de propriedade tenha um formato definido?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, engenharia-de-software, documentação, ecmascript

Outro dia depurando um código aqui na página encontrei algo peculiar.
Parecido com isso:

```js
let a = {};

let b = [1,2,3];
let c = [4,2,3];

a[b]= 1;
a[c]= 2;

console.log(a)       //{ "1,2,3": 1, "4,2,3": 2 }   <--- Preste atenção
```

Ou seja autor da pergunta havia passado um *array* como um [assessor de propriedade](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) usando a [notação de colchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_colchete) e não conseguia mais localizar a propriedade.
Isso, porém, mostrou-me um comportamento interessante da linguagem. Um array, exemplo `["1,2,3"]`, quando passado como um assessor de propriedade usando a notação de colchetes com cria uma propriedade cujo identificador é uma string, no exemplo a string `"1,2,3"`.

Me valendo desse comportamento criei esse código:

```js
const regSlice = /^\d+(,\d+){0,2}$/;

function proxedArray(array) {
  return new Proxy(array, {
    get: (obj, key) => {
      if (typeof key == "string") {
        if (regSlice.test(key)) {
          let [start, stop, step] = key.split(',').map((v) => parseInt(v));
          stop = (stop != undefined) ? stop : start + 1;
          step = (step != undefined) ? step : 1;
          let c = step - 1;
          return obj.slice(start, stop).filter((e, i) => ((c < step) ? c++ : c = 1, c % step == 0));
        }
      }
      return obj[key];
    }
  });
}

const a = proxedArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);

console.log(a[[0, 9, 2]]);            //[ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Código esse que testei em algumas engines([SpiderMonkey](https://ideone.com/uwpHfD), [V8](https://ideone.com/P3hIr4)) obtendo o mesmo resultado conseguido aqui.
O código acima define uma função `proxedArray(array)` que envolve um objeto *array* em um [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) dando ao *array* uma propriedade peculiar, o poder de ser [fatiado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/458596/137387) por índice tal qual uma lista em python:

> *`identificador_do_array"[" fatia "]"`*
> *`fatia = array"[" inicio[, fim[, passo]] "]"`*

Onde:

- `inicio` é o índice onde iniciará a fatia.
- `fim` é o índice onde terminará a fatia. Opcional.
- `passo` é a variação entre os indices do elementos a serem considerados sucessivos. Opcional. Na falta é 1.

Então antes de prosseguir a desenvolver esse código, e colocá-lo em ambiente de produção, preciso fazer a seguinte pergunta:

- ##### Existe documentação no padrão ECMAScript que assegure que a um array ao ser passado como assessor de propriedade tenha um formato definido?

Não encontrei nada a respeito, nem dizendo que sim ou não.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso não é exclusivo de arrays. Qualquer objeto, ao ser usado em um acessor de propriedade, acaba tendo seu método `toString` chamado, e esta string é usada como chave. Ex:

```js
var k = {
    toString: function() {
        console.log('chamando k.toString()');
        return 'k'; // esta será a chave
    }
}

var x = {};
x[k] = 'a';

console.log(x);
console.log(x.k);
```

A saída do código é:

```
chamando k.toString()
{ k: 'a' }
a
```

---

Na [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation) temos o algoritmo que faz a avaliação da expressão `objeto[propriedade]`. Basicamente, em algum ponto o algoritmo (que é complicado, mas "é só" seguir os links da especificação) acaba chamando a operação `ToPropertyKey` ([aqui](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-topropertykey)), que no final chama `toString`.

No caso de arrays, ocorre o mesmo (o método `toString` é chamado e o resultado é usado como chave). Basta mudá-lo para ver:

```js
var x = {};
var b = [1, 2, 3];
b.toString = function() {
    return this.join(' - ');
};
x[b] = 1;
console.log(x); // { '1 - 2 - 3': 1 }
```

---

Este comportamento também é descrito na [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#property_names):

> *Property names are string or Symbol. **Any other value, including a number, is coerced to a string**.*

Ver também:

- [Index ou chave no objeto JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/362777/112052)
- [Os objetos nativos do JS são arrays associativos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/112052)
- [Objetos são semelhantes a arrays?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122341/112052)

Comment: Isso, é [essa](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation) a comprovação que estava procurando e não encontrava. Obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Em JavaScript, objetos são coleções de propriedades. No entanto, uma restrição importante ocorre para as **chaves** dessas propriedades.

Por *design*, a linguagem optou por permitir apenas chaves do tipo `string` ou `symbol`. Desse modo, qualquer outro valor utilizado durante a definição de uma propriedade será convertido ao tipo `string`.

A especificação define esse comportamento semântico [aqui](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-property-accessors); o algoritmo que faz a coerção no caso da chave não ser string ou símbolo está definido na operação abstrata [`ToString`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-tostring) (cuidado para não confundir essa operação com o método `toString`).

Vale salientar que a invocação do método `toString` é apenas uma *consequência*, e não uma razão desse comportamento. Se definido, o método qualificado sob o *well known symbol* [`@@toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) tomará prioridade em relação ao `toString` e `valueOf`.

Veja alguns exemplos:

```js
const values = [
  '1', Symbol('2'), 3, 4n, [5, 6, 7], { 8: 8 }, function() { return 9; }, undefined, null, true, false
];

const obj = {};
for (const value of values) obj[value] = value;
console.log(obj);
```

Repare que esse comportamento pode ser extremamente indesejável em alguns casos. Por curiosidade, esse é um dos motivos que levou à criação do [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), que não possui esse tipo de limitação.

Comment: Aqui *...esse comportamento pode ser extremamente indesejável em alguns casos...* eu concordo pois no caso de instancias de Object não há possibilidade de uso como chave pois sempre serão convertidos em `[object Object]`.

Comment: Por é, @AugustoVasques, até daria para tentar "contornar" isso mudando o `toString` ou `@@toPrimitive`, mas acho que seria gambiarra. Em casos em que isso é o problema, usar `Map` é o melhor mesmo. :)

Comment: Sim é o caso de usar um MAP. No meu caso eu estou implementando um [Inversion List](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/Testes-1#index.js) e um dos requisitos é extrair através índice uma fatia dos dados.