# Java Script - Como exibir valor de uma lista através de uma variável

Tags: javascript, lista, loop, for

Resumo da pergunta:

Habitualmente utilizamos para buscar os valores de uma lista por posição números digitados. Exemplo:

Em uma lista x=[25,10] utilizamos:
x[0] para obter 25
x[1] para obter 10

Certo? Minha dúvida: tem como colocar uma variável dentro de []?
Ficaria assim o código:

```
x =[25,10]

n = [asa0,asa1];
    
    for ntratado in n:
    
       ntratado = asa1[3:4] // eu isolo o número 0 e 1 no loop de asa1 e asa2.
       console.log(x[ntratado]); // *aqui deveria aparecer 25 e 10 no log, já que ntratado traz os valores 0 e 1
```

Essa é a questão. Posso utilizar x[ntratado] ou só posso utilizar x[0] e x[1], para pegar as variáveis da lista?

Comment: Em tempo: sei que o resultado é uma string e já transformei em número usando parseInt(ntratado) , porém sem resultado.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Pergunta editada, conforme solicitação

Comment: Olá Augusto Vasques, tudo bem? Tem como me ajudar nessa dúvida? Obg.

Comment: A pergunta, não faz sentido. A informação necessária para decodificar a sua pergunta ainda está na sua mente e está gerando um hiato entre o que está tentando nos dizer e o que estamos lendo. Tenta explicar levando em conta que não sabemos nada sobre o pretende fazer, tente mostrar o que espera obter e não use variáveis não inicializadas pois para quem lê assumem qualquer valor.

Comment: Entendi. Realmente não deve fazer sentido pq não encontrei nada nas minhas buscas. Mas assim, quando busco uma array de uma lista eu utilizo colcheias [] e a posição numérica da array, certo? o que imagino ser possível é colocar uma variável no lugar. A variável me traz 0 ou1. Por isso coloquei array[0] é o normal. E array[variavel] pode? Essa é a dúvida. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Você está dizendo isso https://ideone.com/7OqrXe ?

Comment: Isso é em python. Mas o que tenho dúvida é em JavaScript. Por isso estou com esse raciocínio, pois em python funciona...mas como realizar isso em JavaScript? Mais uma vez obrigado por sua dedicação e tempo em me ajudar.

Comment: Você quer replicar a sintaxe python de fatiamento em JS? Nessa [minha pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/511056/137387) veja a classe `proxiedArray` que replica em Javascript a sintaxe de fatiamento Python.

Comment: BA TA TA DA !!!! é muito além do que estava buscando e acaba de me abrir novas frentes. Interessante o split com map utilizado e a máscara regSlice. Vou montar de uma outra maneira aqui. Amigo, muito obrigado por sua ajuda e espero que mais pessoas acessem esse seu link. Abs!!!

Comment: Se gostou tanto assim e deseja que a publicação ganhe relevância veja https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas a publicação é destinada a respostas mas também é valida para perguntas.