# Inverter uma frase (PYTHON)

Tags: python

Queria saber como eu inverto e também remover pontuaçao em uma frase do tipo:

Entrada

```
inverte('Anda apanhar um capotinho, Capitu, dizia-lhe ele.')
```

Retorno esperado

```
'ele lhe dizia capitu capotinho um apanhar anda'
```

Coloquei desta forma, mas ainda nao entendo muito bem essa parte, entao sei que esta bem errado...

```
def inverte(frase):
    
    if '-' or ',' or '.' in frase:
        virgula = frase.replace(',', ' ')
    ponto_final = virgula.replace('.', ' ')
    return str.reverse(ponto_final)
    
    if '?' in frase:
            virgula = frase.replace(',', ' ')
    ponto_final = virgula.replace('.', ' ')
    ponto_interrogacao = ponto_final.replace('?', ' ')
    return str.reverse(ponto_interrogacao)
    
    if '!' in frase:
            virgula = frase.replace(',', ' ')
    ponto_final = virgula.replace('.', ' ')
    ponto_interrogacao = ponto_final.replace('?', ' ')
    ponto_exclamacao = ponto_interrogacao.replace('!', ' ')
    return str.reverse(ponto_exclamacao)
```

Comment: Você não precisa fazer um `if` pra verficar se a pontuação está na string, é só fazer o [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). Pra reverter pode utilizar 3 funções: [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) e [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) para, respectivamente, converter a string em uma lista, reverter os itens da lista e unir os textos na lista em uma string, por exemplo, `''.join(reversed(list(text)))`

Comment: esta com replace direto, mas estava dando erro já que algumas frases nao tinham algumas pontuaçoes, e tentei ajeitar assim. quanto seu return, eu havia tentado e me mostra um erro: ExternalError: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sk$type') on line 12

e o codifo ficou:

Comment: def inverte(frase):
    '''
    
    '''
    travessao = frase.replace('-', ' ')
    virgula = travessao.replace(',', ' ')
    dois_pontos = virgula.replace(':', ' ')
    ponto_virgula = dois_pontos.replace(';', ' ')
    ponto_final = ponto_virgula.replace('.', ' ')
    ponto_interrogacao = ponto_final.replace('?', ' ')
    ponto_exclamacao = ponto_interrogacao.replace('!', ' ')
    return str.join(reversed(list(ponto_exclamacao)))

Comment: Seu código está com problema de identação, pesquise como funciona os blocos/escopos no Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer saber como inverter uma frase e remover sua pontuação, uma solução nos parâmetros informados na pergunta pode ser obtida com o módulo de [Operações com Expressões Regulares](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html) utilizando a função [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#re.findall) para obter uma lista de palavras de uma frase a partir dum padrão de correspondência e então inverter essa lista.

```python
import re

m = re.findall(r"[^\-,.?!\s]+", "Anda apanhar um capotinho, Capitu, dizia-lhe ele.")[::-1]

print(*m)
#ele lhe dizia Capitu capotinho um apanhar Anda
```

`findall()` retorna uma lista contendo todas as correspondências não sobrepostas de um padrão de correspondências dentro de uma string.
O padrão de correspondência `[^\-,.?!\s]+` pode ser interpretado como:
Apanhe um ou mais caracteres que não sejam ou `-` ou `,` ou `.` ou `?` ou `!` ou um caractere de espaço.

A [subscrição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/458596/137387) `[::-1]` pega a lista obtida com `findall()` e a retorna invertida.

O código acima trabalhado na forma de uma função:

```python
import re

def inverter(frase, regex=re.compile(r"[^\-,.?!\s]+")):
  return " ".join(re.findall(regex, frase)[::-1])

print(inverter("Anda apanhar um capotinho, Capitu, dizia-lhe ele."))
#ele lhe dizia Capitu capotinho um apanhar Anda
```

Quanto código apresentado na pergunta não faz o que deseja e me abstenho de tecer comentários sobre pois a tentativa de seu reparo só traria confusão.

Comment: Pra complementar, dependendo da definição de "palavra", a regex pode ser ajustada - e ficar cada vez mais complicada - (ex: beija-flor é uma única palavra, deveria ser invertida para "flor beija"?) - Enfim, segue alguns posts relacionados: [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450163/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348269/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401529/112052).

Answer (score 0):

Minha solução pra isso seria usar `split` na frase, transformando cada palavra da frase em um item de uma lista e em seguida inverteria a lista, logo depois o percorreria reformando a nova frase e para remover a pontuação usaria [RegEx](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/185321/131377) siga o exemplo:

```py
import re

def inverterFrase(frase):
    novaFrase  = ''
    for palavra in frase.split()[::-1]: novaFrase += f' {palavra.lower()}'
    novaFrase = re.sub('[^\w\s]',' ',novaFrase)
    
    return novaFrase

resultado = inverterFrase('Anda apanhar um capotinho, Capitu, dizia-lhe ele.')
print(resultado)
```

Comment: oi, entao, ainda nao me ensinaram importar o re e nao fazia ideia, por isso acabei nao especificando. Saberia alguma outra forma sem ser importanto o re?

Comment: @MayaraFigueiredo neste caso pode continuar utilizando `replace`

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo mais ou menos o que vc propôs na sua solução e o que vc comentou nas soluções acima (que queria uma solução sem o uso de `import`), a solução abaixo pode te ajudar:

```
def inverte(frase):
    frase = frase.lower()
    
    pontuacoes = ['.', ',', '!', '?', '-']
    
    for p in pontuacoes:
        frase = frase.replace(p, ' ')

    frase_lista = frase.split()
    frase_lista_invertida = frase_lista[::-1]
    frase_invertida = ' '.join(frase_lista_invertida)
    
    return frase_invertida
```

Alguns detalhes:

- Reparei que na sua saída esperada, a frase toda está minúscula. Por isso, na primeira linha da função uso o método `lower()` para deixar a frase recebida toda em letras minúsculas.
- Na lista `pontuacoes` vc pode colocar todas as pontuações adicionais que deseja ignorar. O loop `for` logo abaixo irá substituir todos esses caracteres por espaço.
- Deixei todos os passos para inverter o texto em variáveis separadas, para que vc consiga identificar todo o processo quando reproduzir o código.

  - `frase_lista` divide a frase em lista de palavras
  - `frase_lista_invertida` inverte a lista de palavras
  - `frase_invertida` pega a lista de palavras invertidas e insere um espaço entre as palavras. Além disso, retorna a lista para uma `string`.

Qualquer dúvida é só falar que tento lhe ajudar.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

fiz dessa forma e deu certo:

```py
def inverte(frase):

    travessao = frase.replace('-', ' ')
    virgula = travessao.replace(',', ' ')
    dois_pontos = virgula.replace(':', ' ')
    ponto_virgula = dois_pontos.replace(';', ' ')
    ponto_final = ponto_virgula.replace('.', ' ')
    ponto_interrogacao = ponto_final.replace('?', ' ')
    ponto_exclamacao = ponto_interrogacao.replace('!', ' ')
    frase_minuscula = str.lower(ponto_exclamacao)
    frase_separada = frase_minuscula.split()
    frase_invertida = frase_separada.reverse()
    return str.join(' ',frase_separada)
```

Answer (score -7):

conheço uma forma de inverter a frase e eu faria dessa forma:

```
palavra = 'Anda apanhar um capotinho, Capitu, dizia-lhe ele.'

print(palavra[::-1])
```

resultado seria esse: .ele ehl-aizid ,utipaC ,ohnitopac mu rahnapa adnA

espero ter ajudado com isso, ainda não conheço uma forma de retirar a pontuação... vou acompanhar também caso eu encontre uma resposta

Comment: Ele quer que inverta as palavras, não as letras.

Comment: para retirar a pontuaçao eu usei: 

def inverte(frase):
    '''
    
    '''
    travessao = frase.replace('-', ' ')
    virgula = travessao.replace(',', ' ')
    dois_pontos = virgula.replace(':', ' ')
    ponto_virgula = dois_pontos.replace(';', ' ')
    ponto_final = ponto_virgula.replace('.', ' ')
    ponto_interrogacao = ponto_final.replace('?', ' ')
    ponto_exclamacao = ponto_interrogacao.replace('!', ' ')
    return ponto_exclamacao